# Cant ping between 2 machines in same subnet

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ping, file-sharing

I have machine A ubuntu with IP address 192.168.1.70 and machine B windows 10 with ip address 192.168.1.45. When i try to connect them using a lan cable i can ping between 2 machines successfully ..Now i have a router of GX Earth 4222 .I connected the two machines in that router.I can browse internet in both machines But .When i try to pring between them i get following output ..This is similar in both machines

```
 ping 192.168.1.45
PING 192.168.1.45 (192.168.1.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I have tried to collect maximum router configuration in this pdf

Here is it http://techtechwin.ml/router.pdf

Should i alter some configuration in my router ...

Will i be able to share files using samba or filezilla without having ping working

This is my firewall configuration

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
23/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
23                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20,21,990/tcp              ALLOW       Anywhere                  
40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
23/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
23 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20,21,990/tcp (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
40000:50000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Assuming that you plugged both computers into Lan ports on the router, the traffic isn't routed and therefore your firewall configuration is irrelevant.

Comment: Routers can block ICMP by default, https://www.quora.com/What-is-ping-blocking-on-a-router So time to go through its manual or contact its vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Your LAN ports are in trunk mode, which means the devices need to do the VLAN tagging. Easiest solution is to change the ports to access mode by setting a VLAN. It is a best practice to avoid using VLAN 1. So 2 would be good. The priority level values range from zero (best effort) to seven (highest), so use 7.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be that ping travels via the ICMP protocol, which isn't the typical TCP or UDP. If ICMP is not allowed, a ping won't work. I'd suggest allowing anything ICMP on the interal-only side.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explicitly answer one small part of your question that has not been directly addressed by other commentors yet - no, ping working is not a pre-requisite for SMB sharing to work.

You might have a firewall that blocks ICMP but allows TCP/139 & TCP/445 (for SMB) and would find that filesharing would be fine despite the lack of a working ping.   That would be fairly unusual, though, and that's part of the reason why people run ping tests as a primitive diagnostic before working their way up to more complicated tests/troubleshooting.